# Unable to fetch data from AWS api gateway with python lambda function to react js frontend using axios

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, axios, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to access data from AWS api gateway. Which works fine without an api-key but after the api-key is enabled the data is not retrived from the server while it works alright with postman testing.

The error in the browser is shows as follows ->

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://bvoj5hykj0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/testresource' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

The server-side lambda function python code is given as follows

```py
import json

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers':{
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Content-Type" : "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,x-api-key",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET"
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        },
        'body': json.dumps("changes saved")
    }
```

The react axios code to retrive the data using api-key is as follows ->

```js
async function testAct(){

    // The below code block is also been tried and returns same response
    // axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    //   "x-api-key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    // }
    // const headers = {
    //   "Content-Type": "application/json",
    //   "Authorization": "xxxxxxxxx-here-is-my-api-keyxxxxx"
    // };

    await axios.get("here is aws-api-url-hidden",{
      headers: {
        "x-api-key": "xxxxxxxxx-here-is-my-api-keyxxxxx"
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      setTestRes(response.data);})
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error);});
  }
```

The API key and API url is right [ I have checked several times ]

The postman response is alright as below ->

[without api-key->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c48pM.jpg)

[with api-key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYEP5.jpg)

I was trying to get the data with aws api-key in reactjs front end. The data comes just fine with postman testing but fails inside react js.

Comment: You haven't handled the preflight `OPTIONS` request. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: Thank You Phil for your help! It really helped me resolve the issue. I had edited the api authentication section in the option section by mistake. Now the code and backend works fine

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the API Gateway to Lambda integration configuration, you will also need to enable CORS for API Gateway. This will handle the preflight `OPTIONS` request as noted by a previous commenter. The browser will perform the `OPTIONS` check, but Postman (to my knowledge) will not.

A few resources to help you configure API Gateway:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/configuring-cors-on-amazon-api-gateway-apis/

Comment: Thank You Josh for your response. The issue is resolved for good !!